# CosmosDB cross partition query error on a singular partition

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've just deleted two collections and then remade them to appear exactly the same as they did before, but without the documents contained within.  The purpose of that was a quick and easy way of clearing out all the documents.

Now when I run queries against those two collection I get the following error:

```
{"Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception.\r\nActivityId: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx"}
```

The collections are not partitioned.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

The DB is currently empty and the query string is: "SELECT * FROM Foo f WHERE f.InstanceId = {guid}".  The collection config is as follows:

```
{
"indexingMode": "consistent",
"automatic": true,
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*",
        "indexes": [
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "Number",
                "precision": -1
            },
            {
                "kind": "Hash",
                "dataType": "String",
                "precision": 3
            }
        ]
    }
],
"excludedPaths": []
```

}

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show 1) the collection configuration (all the details are shown in the `scale` tab in the portal), 2) a sample of the data you're querying, and 3) the query you're trying to run? Otherwise, it's difficult to guess what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, I've amended my questions.

Comment: Can you please also add details on the collection type? You can find that under the Scale details. I really want to confirm whether it's a partitioned collection or a single 10GB fixed-partition collection.

Comment: It is a fixed 10GB partition.  The problem seems to have magically resolved its self.  Any ideas why?  I'm happy the collections are accessible again but this has highlighted a lack of understanding I have that I'm not comfortable with.

Comment: For anyone else that be having this problem. We ran into it this when we initially created a multi-partition collection, noticed the error, deleted the collection, created it as a single-partiton collection and re-seeded the data. There must have been some corrupted data or something because we recreated the collection with the same name. We ended up creating a new collection with a different name altogether and reseeding with data.